# Configure bind9 as slave DNS server w/ master DNS server having dynamic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, slave

I'd like to configure bind9 as DNS slave server doing axfr from a DNS master server (PowerDNS) which is behind a dynamic IP.

The usual configuartion is:

```
zone "example.com" {
  type slave;
  masters { 198.199.120.1; };
  file "/var/lib/bind/db.example.com";
};
```

I can't simply change the IPv4 (198.199.120.1) into a FQDN (mydynaddr.home.net).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get BIND to do that. DNS isn't really designed with dynamic IP addresses in mind, so solving this entirely on the DNS level is likely to be quite tricky. I suspect your easiest option is to rsync the zone files over to the BIND host and then use ssh to do an `rndc reload`.

Comment: That's what I expected. Many thanks for the answer!